# How does Jenkins with MSTest affect CLR memory

Tags: c#, jenkins, bitmap, mstest

I'm running C# MSTest tests from Jenkins jobs on Windows machines. I've run into weird behavior of the CLR's memory management specifically for the Drawing.Bitmap class.

Whem I create a large bitmap within a test method:

```
var bmp = new Bitmap(3000, 3000, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
```

I hit some kind of a memory cap and exceptions get thrown - OutOfMemory or ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid. **This does  not happen if do the same in a non-test program run manually from a compiled binary.** I understand that creating a bitmap in memory requires a lot of it in one chunk (w * h * bytes per pixel). However the cap is being hit much sooner than expected.

Test machines:

- physical Windows 7 machine 8GB RAM
- virtual (VMWare) Windows server 2012 8GB RAM

On the former I can create bitmaps up to only 6MB, on the latter up to 500MB both of which is significantly lower than there is available memory.

Is this a bug or a feature that can be changed somewhere? Note that I want to understand where the problem is and not just look for workarounds for creating huge bitmaps.

Comment: How many tests are you running that call such code? Are there other tests doing similar assignments? Do you release the memory correctly for garbage collection whenever one of these assignments is done?

Comment: I have tried it with single test and no other stuff done in that test as a first test on a machine after restart. Also tried GC.Colect() GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers to no change.

Comment: I don't know much about Jenkins as build server but does it kick off separate Windows processes for a build or do builds run from within a single process?

Comment: I use MS build directly from Jenkins and the tests are run via MS Test agent using the https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/MSTest+Plugin. I think that the build runs in separate process because the tests run within the agents process.